# Составить программу для расчета значения Y

Tags: python

Объясните как составить программу для расчета Cуммы ?
мой код :

```
import math
k = 2;
s = 2;
x = 2;
n = 1;
i=1;
while i <= 1:   
   y = math.sqrt(s**(n*k)+(2*x**k));
   y+=y
   i+=1
print(y)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Высчитывает не правильно:(

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мы не против, составляйте. Будут конкретные вопросы - спрашивайте.

Comment: Вопрос задан :)

Comment: Ты в переменной y хочешь хранить как и промежуточный результат, так и общий. Потому и высчитывает неправильно. Ну и цикл неправильно организован. Хотя бы сам его пройди разок с карандашом.

Comment: `while i <= 1:` - а ведь над знаком суммы стоит `k`, то есть верхняя граница `i` - это `k`, а в вашем коде это никак не проверяется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math
k = 2
s = 2
x = 2
summ = 0
xk = 2*x**k  #эта величина ведь не меняется
for n in range(1, k+1):  #а вот n в цикле меняется
   y = math.sqrt(s**(n*k)+xk);
   summ += y
print(summ)
```

Comment: То есть мне следовало правильно написать цикл..

Comment: Ну по большому счёту - да.